# What handles ajax/json in a MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I used to use asmx to handle ajax calls from pages, but I have read that it's a legacy product, and it is not very compatible with MVC applications. What's the replacement for asmx that is also compatible with MVC nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Action methods in your controllers to give you the Ajax response. You can return any form of data like HTML markup (using a view, Json, string . Image etc...)

```
public ActionResult GetItems()
{
  var items=dbContext.Items;
  return Json(items,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public ActionResult GetAnother()
{     
  return Content("I am just string from ajax");
}
```

You can use same action result for returning HTML markup for an ajax request and normal request using the Request.IsAjax method

```
public ActionResul Getcustomer(int id)
{
  var customer=dbcontext.Customer.Find(id);
  if(Request.IsAjax())
  {
     return View("PartialCustomerForm",customer);
  }
  return View("RegularCustomerForm",customer);

}
```

To call these methods from your page, you can use jquery ajax

```
$.get("@Url.Action("GetItems","Customer")", { id: 3 },function(data){
   //do whatever with the response. //alert(data);
});
```

Comment: How are these members invoked from javascript end? Do I invoke them just like I did in asmx?